# When I click on the view button, instead of opening the card in the index I selected, they all open. Where am I making a mistake?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, project

I added View buttons that show more detailed information about the characters into the card bodies that I created with the data I got from the APIs, but when I click the view button, it opens all of them instead of opening the boxes in the index I selected. Where am I doing wrong. I tried for in instead of forEach, but at that time the first card body opens, the others do not open. When I click on the buttons with console.log(event.target) it shows the buttons correctly but they all refer to the cardbody at index 0

```js
const getAgent = async() =>{
    let url = 'https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents'
    let res = await fetch(url);
    let data = await res.json()
    createAgentBox(data);
   
}

const createAgentBox = (element) =>{

    const agentContainer  = document.querySelector('.agent-container');
    
    let agents = element.data; 
    
    agents.forEach(agent =>{
        
        let agentName = agent.displayName;
        let agentImage = agent.fullPortrait;
        let desc = agent.description;
        let abilitiesImage1 = agent.abilities[0].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesImage2 = agent.abilities[1].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesImage3 = agent.abilities[2].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesImage4 = agent.abilities[3].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesName1 =  agent.abilities[0].displayName;
        let abilitiesName2 =  agent.abilities[1].displayName;
        let abilitiesName3 =  agent.abilities[2].displayName;
        let abilitiesName4 =  agent.abilities[3].displayName;

        let x = `<div class="agentbox">
        <img src=${agentImage} alt="">
        <h1 class='agentname'>${agentName}</h1>
    
        <button class="seeDetails" >View
            <div class="showdetails"  >
                <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
                        <p>${desc}</p>
                    <div class='boxs'>
                        <div class="box1">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage1} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName1}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box2">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage2} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName2}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box3">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage3} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName3}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box4">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage4} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName4}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </button>
             
        
    </div>`
   
        

    agentContainer.innerHTML += x;  

    });   

    let seeDetails = document.querySelectorAll('.seeDetails')

    seeDetails.forEach(seeDetail =>{
        seeDetail.addEventListener('click',showInfos)
    })
    function showInfos(e){
        
        /*open view buttons*/
        let showdetails = document.querySelectorAll('.showdetails');
        showdetails.forEach((showdetail,index) =>{
            showdetail.style.display = 'block'

        })
    }
   
 }

getAgent()


let searcInput = document.querySelector('.searchbox');


searcInput.addEventListener('input',function(){
    const agentsName = document.querySelectorAll('.agentname')
    let container  = document.querySelector('.container')
    
    const search = searcInput.value;
    

    agentsName.forEach((agentName) =>{
        agentName.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
        container.style.height = '100%'
        if(!agentName.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(search)){
            agentName.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
            container.style.height = "100vh"
        }
    })
    
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
}

/*Navbar CSS*/

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fe4655;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fe4655;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 75px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
}

.navlogo {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.3rem;
}

.navlogo > p {
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.navList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}

/*Body*/
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2a1925, #651830, #ff425c);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.search-input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}
.searchbox {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 20rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.searchbox::placeholder {
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
}

.searcBtn {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2a1925, #651830, #ff425c);
}

.agent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.agentbox {
  width: 270px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.agentbox > img {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}

.agentbox > h1 {
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.agentbox > button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  display: flex;
  
}

.showdetails {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  top: 0.01rem;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: none;
  left: 0.2px;
  
}

.showdetails > p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  
}





.boxs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
  
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 > img,
.box2 > img,
.box3 > img,
.box4 > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box1 > p,
.box2 > p,
.box3 > p,
.box4 > p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-xmark {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 7rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navlogo">
            <a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Valorant_logo.svg/2560px-Valorant_logo.svg.png" alt="#" height="30px" width="150px"></a>
            <p>-wiki</p>
        </div>
        <div class="navMenu">
            <ul class="navList">
                <li class="navItem">
                    <a href="/Valorant_wiki/home page/index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="search-input">
            <input type="text" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search Agents...">
            <button class="searcBtn"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
         </div>
         <div class="agent-container">
           
            </div>
         </div>
         
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change code below `/*open view buttons*/` to `e.style.display = 'block'`

Comment: Code overload: please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `document.querySelectorAll(...)` you will get all matching elements over the whole document. That's why all info boxes are being displayed after clicking the "View" button.

```
function showInfos(e){
    
    /* !!! open view buttons*/
    let showdetails = document.querySelectorAll('.showdetails');

    showdetails.forEach((showdetail,index) =>{
        showdetail.style.display = 'block'
    });
}
```

Simply change the code to:

```
function showInfos(e) {
    const showdetails = e.target.querySelector('.showdetails');
    showdetails.style.display = 'block';
}
```

This will get the reference to the clicked element (the button) and execute the query on that element.

**Fully working example**

```js
const getAgent = async() =>{
    let url = 'https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents'
    let res = await fetch(url);
    let data = await res.json()
    createAgentBox(data);
   
}

const createAgentBox = (element) =>{

    const agentContainer  = document.querySelector('.agent-container');
    
    let agents = element.data; 
    
    agents.forEach(agent =>{
        
        let agentName = agent.displayName;
        let agentImage = agent.fullPortrait;
        let desc = agent.description;
        let abilitiesImage1 = agent.abilities[0].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesImage2 = agent.abilities[1].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesImage3 = agent.abilities[2].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesImage4 = agent.abilities[3].displayIcon;
        let abilitiesName1 =  agent.abilities[0].displayName;
        let abilitiesName2 =  agent.abilities[1].displayName;
        let abilitiesName3 =  agent.abilities[2].displayName;
        let abilitiesName4 =  agent.abilities[3].displayName;

        let x = `<div class="agentbox">
        <img src=${agentImage} alt="">
        <h1 class='agentname'>${agentName}</h1>
    
        <button class="seeDetails" >View
            <div class="showdetails"  >
                <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
                        <p>${desc}</p>
                    <div class='boxs'>
                        <div class="box1">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage1} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName1}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box2">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage2} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName2}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box3">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage3} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName3}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box4">
                            <img src=${abilitiesImage4} alt="">
                            <p>${abilitiesName4}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </button>
             
        
    </div>`
   
        

    agentContainer.innerHTML += x;  

    });   

    let seeDetails = document.querySelectorAll('.seeDetails')

    seeDetails.forEach(seeDetail =>{
        seeDetail.addEventListener('click', showInfos)
    })
    
    function showInfos(e) {
        const showdetails = e.target.querySelector('.showdetails');
        showdetails.style.display = 'block';
    }   
 }

getAgent()


let searcInput = document.querySelector('.searchbox');


searcInput.addEventListener('input',function(){
    const agentsName = document.querySelectorAll('.agentname')
    let container  = document.querySelector('.container')
    
    const search = searcInput.value;
    

    agentsName.forEach((agentName) =>{
        agentName.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
        container.style.height = '100%'
        if(!agentName.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(search)){
            agentName.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
            container.style.height = "100vh"
        }
    })
    
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
}

/*Navbar CSS*/

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fe4655;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fe4655;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 75px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
}

.navlogo {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.3rem;
}

.navlogo > p {
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.navList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}

/*Body*/
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2a1925, #651830, #ff425c);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.search-input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}
.searchbox {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 20rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.searchbox::placeholder {
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
}

.searcBtn {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2a1925, #651830, #ff425c);
}

.agent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.agentbox {
  width: 270px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.agentbox > img {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}

.agentbox > h1 {
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.agentbox > button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
  display: flex;
  
}

.showdetails {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  top: 0.01rem;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: none;
  left: 0.2px;
  
}

.showdetails > p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  
}





.boxs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
  
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 > img,
.box2 > img,
.box3 > img,
.box4 > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box1 > p,
.box2 > p,
.box3 > p,
.box4 > p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-xmark {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 7rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navlogo">
            <a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Valorant_logo.svg/2560px-Valorant_logo.svg.png" alt="#" height="30px" width="150px"></a>
            <p>-wiki</p>
        </div>
        <div class="navMenu">
            <ul class="navList">
                <li class="navItem">
                    <a href="/Valorant_wiki/home page/index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="search-input">
            <input type="text" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search Agents...">
            <button class="searcBtn"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
         </div>
         <div class="agent-container">
           
            </div>
         </div>
         
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```